# TabBar displays 9 items instead of a More button

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitabbar

I have a ViewController that has a UITabBar and a webview. When a tab is touched, the webview loads a different URL. I can't seem to figure out how to make sure the More button shows instead of squishing 9 tabs in the tabbar.

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var tabBar: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true);

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int;
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    } else {
        //self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as NSString
        tabBar.delegate = self;
        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.first as UITabBarItem;
        loadPage("http://mywodlog.com");
    }
}
```

[image: TabBar screenshot]

Comment: If it is not vital to create your own instance of a tab bar, I would suggest selecting "Tab bar application" when creating a new project in Xcode. It handles that stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab bars are generally managed by a `UITabBarController`.

Is your `HomeViewController` the root view controller? Replace it with a `UITabBarController`.  Create a separate view controller for the web view.